# DataContext on two object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, binding

I would like to bind two list on a XAML page.

Is there possibilty to make a thing like this :

```
this.DataContext = {listOne,ListTwo} ;
```

Thanks a lot,

Best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use anonymous object for that:

```
this.DataContext = new { One = listOne, Two = listTwo};
```